# Distributed dask matrix from flat text file

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, dask

I'm attempting to read a flat text file (tab-delimited) representation of a matrix into a `dask` array, using `distributed` to distributed the chunks of the array across the cluster.

*(Aside: this is not unlike PySpark's [`sc.textFile`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) method)*

However, it's not clear to me how to parse out the text file into a matrix structure using the tools available. In PySpark, I can do this with a simple `map` with a UDF that splits each line on a space and converts the tokens to a list of floats, and finally the list to an [indexed] numpy array.

I started with the `dask.bag.read_text` method, which has a parameter `collection` that I can set to `False` so it hands me back a bunch of `Delayed` futures. **How do I parse these into the rows of the final matrix?**

```
from dask.bag import read_text
matrix = read_text(filename.txt, collection = False)
```

This returns only a single future. How can I generate a future for every line in the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps here:

#### Break apart a single file into many files with read_text

By default `read_text` treats each file as a single streaming partition.  If you prefer to break data into pieces then use the `blocksize=` keyword argument

```
futures = db.read_text('filename.txt', collection=False, blocksize=10000000)
```

#### Convert futures of lists of text to futures of numpy arrays

Using futures you are in control, presumably you'll create a function to convert your list into a numpy array

```
def list_to_array(L):
    my_array = ...
    return my_array
```

#### Convert futures to small dask.arrays

We convert each future into a dask.array

```
from distributed.collections import futures_to_dask_arrays

arrays = futures_to_dask_arrays(futures)
```

#### Concatenate many arrays into single array

```
import dask.array as da

array = da.concatenate(arrays, axis=0)
```